# how to prevent helm-swoop from returning symbol at point?

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

I would like to invoke `M-x helm-swoop` such that it does NOT return the symbol at point. I find that it always picks up undesired symbols, e.g. when I invoke `M-x helm-swoop` in org-mode, I get `Swoop: \*`, and I then have to delete the `\*` before I can enter my desired search term. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been bugging me as well, for exactly the same reason (swoop in an Org-mode buffer picking up heading characters), so this question motivated me to go and look.

Looking at the source, Helm-swoop calls `helm-swoop-pre-input-function` to populate the prompt, and by default this is set to a function that returns `(thing-at-point 'symbol)`, which is what causes the problem in headings.

A quick test with the following in my init file seems to work:

```
(setq helm-swoop-pre-input-function
       (lambda () nil))
```

This could certainly be improved by, for example, keeping the default behaviour in non-Org buffers but as I'm only really using swoop in Org buffers this is good enough for me.

Comment: Warning, untested: `(add-hook 'org-mode (lambda () (setq-local help-swoop-pre-input-function (lambda () nil))))`